# Partial column grouping and converting sql column values to JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have sql table which contains the data as below,

SqlTable:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|PID                | LID   |Name               | Value             |
|-------------------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|73B                | CD    |Technolgy          | ELECTRICAL        |
|-------------------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|73B                | CD    |Source             | 100               |
|-------------------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|73B                | CD    | Estimation        | 50                |
|-------------------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|73B                | CD    |Capacity           | Full              |
|-------------------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

I want select the data from above table by grouping columns PID and LID and then convert the Name and value columns as JSON.

Expected output from the select statement is,

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|PID                | LID   |JSON                      |
|-------------------|-------|--------------------------|
|73B                | CD    |{"Technolgy":"ELECTRICAL",|
|                   |       |"Source":"100",           |
|                   |       |"Estimation" : "50",      |
|                   |       |"Capacity" : "Full" }     |
|-------------------|-------|--------------------------|
```

is there any built in function there in SQL server or select statement query options?

Comment: *"is there any built in function there in SQL server or select statement query options?"* yes, [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can format query results as JSON with `FOR JSON`, this is not an option here, because you have variable `key: value` pairs. One possible approach in this situation is to bulid the JSON with string aggregation. If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may try with `STRING_AGG()`. For earlier versions, you need to use `FOR XML PATH`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   PID varchar(10),
   LID varchar(10),
   Name varchar(50),
   Value varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (PID, LID, Name, Value) 
VALUES   
   ('73B', 'CD', 'Technolgy',  'ELECTRICAL'),
   ('73B', 'CD', 'Source',     '100'),
   ('73B', 'CD', 'Estimation', '50'),
   ('73B', 'CD', 'Capacity',   'Full')
```

Statement with `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT 
   PID, 
   LID, 
   CONCAT(
      '{',
      STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', Name, '":"', Value, '"'), ','),
      '}'
   ) AS JSON 
FROM Data
GROUP BY PID, LID
```

Statement with `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   d.PID, 
   d.LID, 
   JSON = CONCAT(
      '{',
      STUFF(
         (
         SELECT CONCAT(',"', Name, '":"', Value, '"')
         FROM Data 
         WHERE PID = d.PID AND LID = d.LID
         FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, N''
         ),   
      '}'
   )
FROM Data d
```

Result:

```
PID LID JSON
73B CD  {"Technolgy":"ELECTRICAL","Source":"100","Estimation":"50","Capacity":"Full"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to construct the value as a string:

```
SELECT d.PID, d.LID, 
       CONCAT('{', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', Name, '":"',  Value, '"'), ', '), '}') as jsonstring
FROM Data d
GROUP BY d.PID, d.LID;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=368875018b77042b784651647fb63d2a) is a db<>fiddle.